# Random Java/JVM SIGSEGV crashes, how to debug?

Tags: java, segmentation-fault, jvm

This problem has been plaguing me for the last few months and I'm at a loss on how to solve it.

I'm running a bot which connects to an online crypto exchange to do some automated trading. It monitors all coins on the exchange at the same time. I run multiple papertrading accounts in the same JVM where, per account, each coin uses a separate thread for doing the calculations based on coin price. I also run numerous of threads (sometimes more than one per coin, if I monitor different candle length) which run the WebSocket connections to the exchange. Every hour I draw a chart with [JFreeChart](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart), per coin, per account, to show the buy/sell signals.

For some time now I've been getting random crashes in the JVM. These appear to happen randomly throughout my code and also at random intervals. I can be runnning the application for a couple of days without any issue, other days the application crashes multiple times in one day. Things I've noticed are:

- I've been getting more and more crashes since I started to demand more from the application and system. For example: when I switched to processing realtime prices instead of once every second the crashes would occur more often. Also, the crashes happen a lot when I'm drawing the charts, drawing and saving these charts causes a temporarily high load on the system.
- The crashes happen most of the time during the drawing of the chart in `org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG` and while doing computations related to building a `BarSeries` object from `org.ta4j.core.BaseBarSeriesBuilder` or `org.ta4j.core.BarSeries.addBar`. But this is most likely because the application spends the most amount of CPU time in those methods.

Things I tried:

- Disabling the realtime prices and drawing of the charts will result in less crashes, but they are not gone.
- I thought that maybe the high thread count caused for some instability. The drawing of the charts was very unoptimized previously as it spawned a thread per chart to draw. I now changed that to just use one single thread to draw all charts (`BlockingExecutor`), but this didn't cause any less JVM crashes.
- Prices are updated in `Candlestick` objects by the WebSocket threads. These candlesticks are then passed on through a queue to the appropriate coin threads. I thought that maybe the SIGSEGV was happening because I was updating the price in a `Candlestick` object while it was being used by a coin thread , either by drawing or by doing some calculations. I'm now creating deep copies of every `Candlestick` object I pass to the queue.
- Switching to new hardware: I was first hosting the application on my own server. I thought that maybe the issues were related to some faulty hardware or limited amount of resources I had available on my own server. I'm now renting a VPS with 4x the amount of RAM and 6 cores instead of 4.
- Upgrading Java to latest version: I tried Java versions 8, 11 and 14, none of them solved the issue.
- Using different GC settings: I tried all of them.
- Increasing memory the JVM can use with `-Xmx`: I'm now running the JVM with `-Xmx4000m`, which should be more than enough if I do a profile run and monitor the memory usage. I'm not completely sure if this had any effect. The crashes seemed to be occurring somewhat less often, but as I've said before, the crashes are at completely random intervals so I can't really do any comparison here. Also, I don't really want to increase it any further because I'm running other applications on the same VPS which also need a share of the precious RAM.

I'm really clueless on how to approach this further as I'm not very experienced in dealing with these kinds of errors, so any help is greatly appreciated. See [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l3strxwxgswih91/AADaGR5VPnNga9zhQrq2VMjWa?dl=0) for the last few crashlogs.

The libraries I'm using are as follows:

```
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation project(':binance-java-api')
    implementation project(':CoinGecko-Java')

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jfree/jfreechart
    implementation group: 'org.jfree', name: 'jfreechart', version: '1.0.19'

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.6'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ta4j/ta4j-core
    implementation group: 'org.ta4j', name: 'ta4j-core', version: '0.13', classifier: 'sources'
    implementation group: 'org.ta4j', name: 'ta4j-core', version: '0.13', classifier: 'javadoc'
    implementation group: 'org.ta4j', name: 'ta4j-core', version: '0.13'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.awaitility/awaitility
    testImplementation group: 'org.awaitility', name: 'awaitility', version: '3.0.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.10.19'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.11.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-properties
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-properties', version: '2.11.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.11'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/jcommander
    implementation group: 'com.beust', name: 'jcommander', version: '1.78'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/me.tongfei/progressbar
    implementation group: 'me.tongfei', name: 'progressbar', version: '0.9.0'
```

Comment: Can you post the hs_err.... file?

Comment: It's listed at the bottom of my post as a Dropbox link.

Comment: Do you maybe use some 3-party-lib that uses nativ code? Also, are you sure that everything you do multi-threaded is thread-safe?

Comment: I've added the libs i'm using in my post. I'm not sure if any of those use JNI (that's what you mean right?). For the thread-safety: one can only be so sure as of what his own perception is for how thread-safe the application is ;). I can never be 100% sure there are no issues there, I tried my best to solve any possible issues as explained in my post.

Comment: @Daan Can you make a minimal example, that will still crash?

Comment: That's the problem. I can't really isolate it because it only occurs when I have a lot of stuff going on (e.g. listen to a lot of coins at the same time, have multiple accounts, etc)

Comment: ZGC? Good luck with that. Seriously, it is an experimental GC in JDK 14 - you even had to add `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions`. When I last tried ZGC in production, it also crashed. Do you have `hs_err_pid` files from runs with other GCs?

Comment: I'd also suggest to run without JDWP.

Comment: I'll give it another go with the default GC and without JDWP. It's been over a month since I fiddled with that so don't have any logs of crashes with the default GC. If I remember correctly last time I used the default GC was while I was running Java 11, never used it with 14. I'll keep you guys posted on how it goes

Comment: It crashed again (after only 10 minutes this time) with the default GC and without the debug options. I've attached a logfile [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o1zd36xh73vdq0x/hs_err_pid1431208_defaultgc.log?dl=0)

Comment: Could you somehow run with `-XX:+PrintAssembly` and give us the assembly code of `ava.math.BigDecimal.<init>([CIILjava/math/MathContext;)V`? (Furthermore try running in interpreted mode only (`-Xint`). Another thing to try is to exclude the crashing method from being compiled